# flow input type - why we need to type double array like type[][]?

Tags: javascript, typescript, fp-ts

I'm using functional programming library and there is pipe-like function called flow. It's usage looks like this

```
flow(
  map(item => item.toString())
)([1, 2, 3])
```

Flow is generic so it takes in this case 2 type arguments. The first one is for input ([1, 2, 3]) and the second one is for what the entire flow returns (in this case it is ['1', '2', '3']. Knowing that I'm typing the flow

```
flow<number[], string[]>...
```

but then I get error which disappears only when I type it like

```
flow<number[][], string[]>...
```

The type definition for flow looks like this

```
export declare function flow<A extends ReadonlyArray<unknown>, B>(ab: (...a: A) => B): (...a: A) => B
```

Tell me please why I need to do double array in this case please.

Comment: Well it's strongly about Typescript and the way ts typing works. fp-ts is written in Typescript, using Typescript typings and the library is just an addon. Basing on attached code I'm wondering why Typescript requires double [][] next to type in this case.

Comment: Ah, I read a bit quickly. Thanks for the clarification. Thought we were talking about flow types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `flow` function is designed to handle more than one argument. The generic type `A` represents the type of these arguments as a *tuple*.

While typing `A` as `number[][]` seemingly solved your problem, you are really supposed to type it as `[number[]]`, representing a *single* argument which is of type `number[]`.

```
flow<[number[]], string[]>(
  map(item => item.toString())
)([1, 2, 3])
```

Typing `flow` with multiple different arguments would look like this:

```
const someOperator = (arg_0: number[], arg_1: string) => [arg_1]

flow<[number[], string], string[]>(
    someOperator
)([1, 2, 3], "")
```